# Assemble all gradle build artifacts into a single directory

Tags: gradle, multi-project

We're moving from Maven to Gradle and are struggling with one thing. 
We have a multi-project Gradle-project based on the POMs from Maven.
Most of it works fine, but we cannot find out a way to collect the WAR-files and ZIP-files which are the result from building the sub-projects. Each sub-project represents a micro service.
We have found (also on Stackoverflow) ways to collect all of the jars and third party libs into a directory. However, we are looking for a way to collect the resources and libraries per micro service.
In Maven we did something like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>Publish/</outputDirectory>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>....</groupId>
                                <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>....</groupId>
                                <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>war</type>
                            </artifactItem>
```

I would like to end up with a directory where I can find:

```
project1.war
project2.war
project3.zip
etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is hand-rolled but is simple, and offers flexibility if you need to tweak anything.

Below is a `build.gradle` in the root directory. For each subproject, it will:

- Define a `copyArtifacts` task that copies `war` and `zip` files from the subproject's `build/libs` folder (using appropriate `baseName`, `version`, etc) to `root/dist`.
- If a `war` task is found, then configure it so that it runs `copyArtifacts` afterwards.

This can be easily changed to look for other task names, match different filenames, etc. (One might want to delete older versions of a given artifact before the copy, and so on.)

```
subprojects { Project subProject ->
    task copyArtifacts {
        doLast {
            def baseName = subProject.archivesBaseName
            def version = subProject.version
            def group = subProject.group
            def DIST_DIR = "${rootDir}/dist"
            def SRC_DIR = "${buildDir}/libs"

            ant.mkdir(dir: DIST_DIR)
            ant.copy(todir: DIST_DIR) {
                fileset(dir: SRC_DIR,
                includes: "${baseName}*${version}*.war,${baseName}*${version}*.zip")
            }
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        def warTask = subProject.tasks.find { it.name == 'war' }
        if (warTask) { 
            warTask.finalizedBy(copyArtifacts)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost works, but ZIPs are stored in the distributions-directory. I've added a second tasks for projects which built a ZIP. It works and I only needed to change the main build.gradle and not any of the subprojects. That's seems easier to manage.

Answer (score 3):

In each of the projects which produce an artifact (eg zip) you'll add the artifact to a configuration. See [artifact management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html)

eg:

```
configurations {
   archives
}
task myZip(type: Zip) { ... }
artifacts {
   archives myZip
}
```

Then, in the uber project you'll use another configuration to reference the artifacts and a zip task to bundle them

```
configurations {
   uber
}
dependencies {
   uber project(path: ':project1', configuration: 'archives')
   uber project(path: ':project2', configuration: 'archives')
   uber project(path: ':project3', configuration: 'archives')
}
task uberZip(type: Zip) {
   from configurations.uber
   archiveName 'uber.zip'
   destinationDir "$buildDir/uber"
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting as it uses built-in functionality. However, I don't want an uber-zip, but rather several default artifacts (WARs and ZIPs) copied to a central directory. I don't know if that is also possible with these functions?

Comment: Simple, just replace the `uberZip` task with an `uberCopy` task of type `Copy`. You can keep the `from` clause

Comment: hi lance-java, what are the other parameters that can be given in :

uber project(path: ':project1', configuration: 'archives') ??

Is it possible to give a file that is generated in project1? Would that be zipped?

Comment: You'd leave the `uber` project as it was. But you'd change the individual projects to `artifacts { archives someTaskWhichCreatesTheFilesYouWant }`. Be sure to configure the [TaskOutputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs) in `someTaskWhichCreatesTheFilesYouWant`